# Find sample files for certain mimetypes

Tags: file, testing, integration-testing

I am writing an integration test for some kind of file validator. The list of allowed mimetypes is:

```
    [
        // jpeg
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/jpeg',

        // png
        'image/png',
        'image/x-png',

        // bitmap
        'image/bmp',
        'image/x-bmp',
        'image/x-bitmap',
        'image/x-xbitmap',
        'image/x-win-bitmap',
        'image/x-windows-bmp',
        'image/ms-bmp',
        'image/x-ms-bmp',
        'application/bmp',
        'application/x-bmp',
        'application/x-win-bitmap',
    ]
```

I want to pass a sample file of each mimetype to the validator and check if it detects it correctly. But how do I find sample images for each of those? For example, where to get a `image/pjpeg`? I don't want to install a lot of software that can produce those files. Is there maybe an open library where files by mimetype can be found?